# Two way binding of date in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular

I've a question about 2-way binding in Angular 2.0.
In my view I show the selected date (month and year) + days in the month.
There are buttons to go to the next or previous month.
But when I click them the showed date is not updated but it is successfully updated in the model. And the days in the month are updated correctly (with ngFor).
Does anybody know the correct way to update the date in the view?

View:

```html
<span>
  {{date | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}
</span>

<button (click)="goToPreviousMonth()">Previous month</button>
<button (click)="goToNextMonth()">Next month</button>

<div *ngFor="#week of weeks">
    <!-- Show days -->
</div>
```

Component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgModel} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'monthview',
    templateUrl: './monthview.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class MonthView {
   weeks:any = [];
   date:Date;

   public goToMonthFromCurrent(addMonth:number) : void {
        // Update date
        this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + addMonth);

        // Some other code to calculate days of month... 

        // This will update the date in view
        this.date = new Date(this.date.getTime());
   }

   public goToNextMonth() : void {
        this.goToMonthFromCurrent(1);
   }

   public goToPreviousMonth() : void {
        this.goToMonthFromCurrent(-1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change a property of an object Angulars change detection doesn't recognize the change. Angular only compares identity of the object instance.

Create a new `Date` instance instead of changing the exising one.

Comment: Thanks. 'this.date = new Date(this.date.getTime());' was indeed the solution (updated solution in question). What would the solution be with notifying angular about change?